# How to set an interval for tickmarks?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-visualization

I'm trying to have tickmarks at an interval of 50. MajorGrid works fine, but I can not find any way to get the tickmarks of the yAxis align to the gridlines of the majorgrid. Currently I'm using this:

```
chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("statistic")
{
    AxisX = ...
    AxisY = new Axis
    {
        MajorGrid =
            new Grid
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    LineColor = Color.Black,
                    LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid,
                    Interval = 50,
                    IntervalOffset = 0
                },
        Title = yAxisDesc,
        Minimum = yAxisRange.Item1,
        Maximum = yAxisRange.Item2
    }
}
```

to get this:

[image: Current result lacking alignment of ticks to grid.]

I tried modifying MajorTickMark to no avail.

What do I have to change?

Comment: Your posted code does not show any changes to `MajorTickMark`. There should be something like `chartArea.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Interval = 50;`

Comment: Additionally, you probably need `chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 50` as well.

Comment: Thx @jstreet, this has done the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int xmax = 100;

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 50;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorTickMark.Interval = 50;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 50;

        for (int x = 1; x < xmax; x++)
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, 5 * x);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jstreet,
I found the following solution:

```
AxisY =
new Axis
    {
        MajorGrid =
            new Grid
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    LineColor = Color.Black,
                    LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid,
                    Interval = 50,
                    IntervalOffset = 0
                },
        Title = yAxisDesc,
        Minimum = yAxisRange.Item1,
        Maximum = yAxisRange.Item2,
        LabelStyle = new LabelStyle{Interval = 50, Enabled=true,IntervalOffset = 0,IsEndLabelVisible = true},
        MajorTickMark =
            new TickMark
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    Interval = 50,
                    IntervalOffset = 0,
                },
    }
```

However, using only MajorTickMark or LabelStyle doesn't result in the desired chart. This is it now:

[image: desired alignment of ticks and grid]